# Matlab concatenate variable string without curly braces

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I'm trying to concatenate a series of strings in a loop into a variable array but the resulting strings are always within curly braces. Why does this happen, and how can I concatenate the string without them? Thanks

```
subs = {'abc001' 'abc002' 'abc003' 'abc004'};
for i = 1:size(subs,2) 
    subject = subs(i); 
    files_in(i).test = strcat('/home/data/','ind/',subject,'/test_ind_',subject,'.mat'); 
end

files_in(1)

% ans = 
%   test: {'/home/data/ind/abc001/test_ind_abc001.mat'}
```

I would like it to be:

```
test: '/home/data/ind/abc001/test_ind_abc001.mat'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subs` is a cell array. If you index it using `()` notation, you will *also* get a cell array.

```
a = {'1', '2', '3'};
class(a(1))
%   cell
```

To get the *string inside the cell array* you need to use `{}` notation to index into it.

```
class(a{1})
%   char
```

When you use `strcat` with cell arrays, the result will be a cell array. When you use it with strings, the resut will be a string. So if we switch out `(k)` with `{k}` we get what you expect.

```
for k = 1:numel(subs)
    subject = subs{k};
    files_in(k).test = strcat('/home/data/ind/', subject, '/test_ind_', subject, '.mat');
end
```

A few side notes:

1. Don't use `i` as a variable. `i` and `j` are used in MATLAB to indicate `sqrt(-1)`.
2. It is recommended to use `fullfile` to construct file paths rather than `strcat`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and those side notes! I'm new to matlab, so I'm still picking things like that up.